# Result: NaN will not work?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nan

Within the app I have different activity pages that call for the user to enter numerical data.  I think of storing the data as below so I can use it on the final activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String variable1 = input.getText().toString();
    Double.parseDouble(variable1); //stores information put into variable
        { Intent myintent = (new Intent(step1.this,step2.class));
        myintent.putExtra("variable1",variable1);
        startActivity(myintent);
```

I do this same process for all the other activities up to the final one where I have:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iie);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //retrieves variables stored for formula

    if(extras !=null){
        double variable1 = extras.getDouble("VARIABLE1");
        double vari2 = extras.getDouble("VARI2");
        double vari3 = extras.getDouble("VARI3");
        double finalvari = extras.getDouble("finalvari");
        double solution= ((((vari2 - vari1) / (vari3) + finalvari)));

        String lastString = "Result:" + solution; //prints out
        TextView lastText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution1);
        lastText.setText(lastString);
    }
```

I don't have any errors, but when I get to this final activity it prints out "Result:NaN". I'm trying to figure out why it is printing `NaN`; everything is set as a double.

What could cause this?

***Update***
@Melquiades

Yes I replaced the strings with the doubles as shown below:

```
'c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         double variable1 =  Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString()); //stores information put into variable
        { Intent myintent = (new Intent(step1.this,step2.class));
        myintent.putExtra("variabele1",variabele1);
        startActivity(myintent);
        '
```

Then in my final activity that is suppose to print the answer:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iie);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //retrieves variables     stored         formula

if (extras != null){
        double variable1 = extras.getDouble("variable1");
        double vari2 = extras.getDouble("vari2");
        double vari3 = extras.getDouble("vari3");
        double engagement = extras.getDouble("engagement1");
        double solution= ((((vari2-variable1)/(vari3))+finalvari));
            String lastString = "Result:" +solution; //prints out 
            TextView lastText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution1);
                    lastText.setText(lastString);
```

Decided to post some more to potentially help like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In the launching end, you just set one extra `variable1`.

In the receiving end, you attempt to four values from extras:

```
double variable1 = extras.getDouble("VARIABLE1");
double vari2 = extras.getDouble("VARI2");
double vari3 = extras.getDouble("VARI3");
double finalvari = extras.getDouble("finalvari");
```

`getDouble()` will return `0.0` if the key is not present.

Now, in here

```
double solution= ((((vari2-vari1)/(vari3)+finalvari)));
```

you divide by zero, which in floating point math causes the result to be Not a Number (NaN).

Comment: As noted, I have set all extra variables, just to save time for you guys to read code, I didn't post the remaining variables.  Every other variable mentioned above is coded the same as variable1 in terms of being set (coded like the first bit of code).  

I don't get how I'm dividing by zero still if I have vari3 set to 5 and finalvari is set to 1 (when I run through the other activities to enter the variable data in the app).  Thank you for your post above.

Comment: Ok, then just set a debugger breakpoint there and inspect the variables to see where the NaN comes to your expression. Then go back step by step to inpect where the variable values come from.

Comment: I switched the equation and now am getting 0.0 when I don't divide like you were saying.  But am confused on why I am getting 0.0 now, I have done the same for the other variables as I did with variable1.

Answer (score 1):

Key issue is that put `String` into intent:

```
String variable1 = input.getText().toString();
Double.parseDouble(variable1); //stores information put into variable
//...
myintent.putExtra("variable1",variable1); <- variable1 is a string,
```

and when you extract it later with [getDouble()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getDouble%28java.lang.String%29) you will get, quote :

> 0.0 if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key

So you should put `double` in your intent instead :

```
double variable1 = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
myintent.putExtra("variable1",variable1);
```

Please note, it is very important to use identical key String for mapping, when you extract your double, i.e. use "variable1", case-sensitive :

```
double extractedVar1 = extras.getDouble("variable1");
```

You could use extras.[containsKey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#containsKey%28java.lang.String%29) to verify that your mapping exists.

Comment: so remove the string part and instead include what you just mentioned?

Comment: yes. I mean you expect `double` in your intent, don't you ? So, put `double` there, not a `String`. You may want to check double you put there first, for example : `double variable1 = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());` if (variable1 > 0) { // put into intent }

Comment: going to try that now, will get back to this thread in a little and try that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

All the advices are correct. but you are doing one cardinal mistake...

When you're sending your variables, you do:

```
myIntent.putExtra("variable1", variable1);
```

Then when your receive, you do:

```
double variable1 = extras.getDouble("VARIABLE1");
```

Your keys are NOT THE SAME. 'variable1' and 'VARIABLE1' are not equal, hence instead of the value of variable 1, you are probably getting 0 instead, and all your calculations are wrong.

For this reason, it's a good practice to use static finals for keys. Declare in your first activity:

```
public static final String KEY_VARIABLE1 = "variable1";
```

Use it when inserting in an intent:

```
myIntent.putExtra(KEY_VARIABLE1, variable1);
```

And when retrieving:

```
double variable = extras.getDouble(ActivityWhereThisKeyIsDeclared.KEY_VARIABLE1);
```

Do it for all your variables.

Comment: I fixed the keys, but am still getting NaN.  For example when I go through the activities for the variables I use, (50,100,5,1) so when I plug it out by hand I get (((100-50)/5)+1).  Do I have to do stat finals for the keys to not get the NaN (will go back and fix that later) but just trying to get rid of the NaN.

Comment: Have you used doubles instead of Strings where advised? Add Log.d() in your receiving activity and output the values of variable1, vari2, vari3 and finalvari - what are they? Also, add current code in your post.

Comment: If you made sure you put `double`, and not `String`, print what you extract, as Melquiades suggests. You could extract values with intent.`getDoubleExtra`  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String, double) instead of extracting `Bundle` first. That way you could specify default value, so you will never get 0.0 in case they are not present.

Comment: I would post what I put, but it won't let me since I only have a 5 reputation and need a 10 because the code is too long to post in a comment and cannot write in my answer.

Comment: Still your keys are different, when sending you're using 'variabele1', and when receiving 'variable1'. Use static finals for keys as suggested,  then report back.

Comment: So I implemented static finals for keys per step and variable but still get NaN.  Going to update the top in the morning @Melquiades

Comment: @JonathanQuant Please, put a breakpoint, or simply Log.d value of all extracted double variables : `var1`, `var2`, `var3` that are used to calculate double `solution` and post what you've got.